# image file is not uploading in django?

Tags: ajax, django, django-models

I am trying to upload the images via ajax and the front-end code seems to be working and I have the image data in the `request.FILES`. but the images are not being uploaded on the server side.

here is my django view:

```
@login_required
def update_profile_image(request):
    print(request.FILES)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()

            context = {'None': 'none'}
            return JsonResponse(context)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('None')
```

the form is valid but the image is not uploaded in the MEDIA directory.

my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{ self.user.username } Profile'
```

and form:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

btw this is my AJAX call (which as I said seems to be working).

```
$(document).on('submit', '#profile_edit_form', function(event){

  event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url         : "/users/update_profile_image/",
            type        : 'POST',
            //enctype     : "multipart/form-data",   //it is done inside jquery
            data        : formdata,
            cache       : false,
            contentType : false,
            processData : false,
            success : function(data) {
              console.log('success');
              //$('#profile_picture').html(data.)

            },
            error: function(data) {
              console.log('image-fail');
            }
        });

});
```

What am I doing wrong in my view function?

thanks!

Comment: Please show your form code.

Comment: @ger.s.brett done!

Comment: Everything looks right from here at first glance, have you enabled media uploads and configured the settings for it in `settings.py`?

Comment: @GiannisKatsini I have added `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')` and `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` to `settings.py`. what do you mean "enabling media uploads?"

Comment: You are aware that this will upload to "media/profile_pics"?

Comment: @ger.s.brett of course but they are not uploaded there

Comment: Can you remove the default value from the field and check the error?

Comment: @ger.s.brett if you mean the deafult value of  `class Profile`, I removed the default value. but nothing happens when I try to change the 'profile picture' by ajax. It is the same. Of course I can not make a new user now.